# Difference between Rxjs 'ajax' operator and the http methods like GET , PUT ,POST?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am learning about operators in rxjs and came across the ajax() operator, this operator seems to be very similar to the http methods. Is there any difference between them or is it only about the different scenarios we might have to use them in? If so then which scenario would we use the ajax operator as an alternative to the http methods. I haven't been able to find any answers talking about the difference between the two , so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `ajax()` function from RxJS is used to create an observable for an [AJAX Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX). Theoretically you could use either AJAX Request or the Angular `HttpClient` to trigger an HTTP request. Both would return the same response. However if you are using Angular, it's easier to use the built-in `HttpClient` methods since they readily support RxJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Ajax operator creates an observable for an ajax request. It is used to make API calls. We can perform all http request methods with this ajax operator. It converts a normal ajax call to an observable and emits the data as an observable. [rxjs ajax](https://satyapriyamishra111.medium.com/ajax-operator-in-rxjs-9fa2b9261769)

So the first one allows you to convert an ajax call in to an observable , instead the httpClient is a service provided by Angular